# How to update hadoop/hbase/hive configuration without down time?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I've heard someone said that you can just modify the config of hadoop and restart the namenode and datanode one by one because of the QJM will handle the master failover, so it would not have "down time".

I don't know if this is true. and how to do with hbase or hive if you want to update config runtime?

Comment: Which configs do you mean exactly by "the config of hadoop"? Aren't Hbase and Hive just more tools in the "configs of Hadoop"?

Comment: @cricket_007 such as "hbase.ipc.server.max.callqueue.size"

Comment: You need to restart some service in Hbase. If you want a high-availability rollover like the Namenode, I think that is dependent upon the specific tool itself, and not so much the rest of hadoop

Comment: That depends on the config you updating is a server-level config or client-level config. Only updating the server-level config will require a reboot of the service. If you have a HA cluster, which has 2 NNs, you certainly can boot one at a time, the other will automatically take over. But again, not all config updates require you to restart NN.

Comment: If you're using CM or Ambari, they should manage HA.  If you're not using either cluster manager then you'll have to setup everything yourself.  HDFS and YARN support HA (see http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html and http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html) but HBase and Hive don't directly so you might have to setup a proxy to accomplish this.